# "Won't everyone be amazed"

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis

I wonder why the word order of this phrase is reversed in the sentence below: *won't everyone be amazed*.

> But if he somehow can pull off this trick, boy oh boy, won’t everyone be amazed. This is ultimately what makes North Korea so irresistible to Mr. Trump. There are indeed lots of bad actors and dangerous regimes and looming threats on the world stage. But which regime is seen as the most unpredictable, the most isolated, the craziest of crazy? If Mr. Trump can crack this nut, he’ll surely get the adulation — not to mention the Nobel Peace Prize — that he is so desperate for.

Comment: What alternative are you considering? @Herr Pink seems to explain why not "Will everyone be amazed?" But your reference to word order suggests that you were proposing "Everyone won't be amazed."

Comment: +1 Good question. Why the close votes?

Comment: @Chaim See my comment at Herr Pink.

Comment: Can you pleaes please explain what you mean by "the word order of this phrase is reversed…"? I missed something there, if no-one else did.

Comment: Folks, just show where to find the answer, and help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It's rhetorical, implying that the author feels that yes; everybody will be amazed.

Compare it to a sentence like "won't you be my friend?" - it's not likely that someone is legitimately asking someone not to be their friend.

Or, if you want to steal rhetorical devices from a video game, think about Bioshock's "is a man not entitled to the sweat of his brow?", wherein the person asking the question quite clearly feels that the subject in question should have that entitlement.

Comment: I see it rhetoric. But why does it end with Period not Queston mark?

Comment: Not quite the same thing.

Comment: @Kris I see, but I don't understand. What is not the same thing as what?

Comment: @Mankak, of course a question is being asked and of course that requires a question mark. Rhetorical questions like this are still questions, and still need their marks. To drop the mark must at least remove the power, even if it doesn't completely detroy the rhetoric… as should be obvious from the example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no question mark because there is no question being asked. If the entirety of the sentence were “Won’t everyone be amazed?” there would be a question mark. In the  full sentence above, however, the phrase is added as a way to show the author’s/speaker’s skepticism that “he somehow can pull off this trick.

That’s my impression of the text, using “but if” and “somehow” as context clues denoting skepticism.

Hope that helps to clarify things.

Answer (score 0):

What a question!

It's an interrogative form of **exclamatory sentence** that uses word order inversion just like an interrogative. It ends in a period (or an exclamation mark), not a mark of interrogation.

It helps focus on the exclamatory nature:

> "Isn't she beautiful." (Wow! She **is** beautiful.)
>   "Won't everyone be amazed." (Everyone **would surely be** amazed.)
>   "Aren't I lucky!" (I **am** lucky, any doubt?)